# How to invalidate Doctrine's result cache on multiple servers?

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, redis

I'm developing a Symfony 3 Application, where I use Doctrine as ORM.

Now, I'm planning to use APCu for Result Cache as Doctrine's docs describes: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache

Easy as that to cache result:

```
$query->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'my_custom_id');
```

And I can invalidate it as following:

```
$cacheDriver->delete('my_custom_id');
```

The problem is, that this code works only for **one** server; but in production, mi app is deployed into three servers, so... if I invalidate a cache entry, it is only invaldated on one of the three servers.

Is there any way to invalidate cache on multiple servers using ACPu? Or, is preferible to work with another kind of cache, ie Redis, on a separated server?

Comment: I would be interested in a solution to this. Currently I'm using ZMQ to synchronise cache clearing, which isn't ideal.

Comment: Sorry @dk80 , I ended up using Redis on a separate server.